# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE doesn't print with output and pooling turned on

Tags: toad

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ) doesn't print output however output and spooling are turned on. "Procedure is completed successfully" message is displayed without any output. When run in SQLPLUS it throws errors.

Do you have any idea to check? I tried the DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE() etc.

Comment: While I agree that a neg vote should be accompanied by an explanation otherwise it doesn't teach anyone anything, calling names and using profanity are just going to get your question closed and you booted. A bad way for a new user to get started here.  Instead, consider reviewing your question.  Don't type in all caps and make sure all relevant info is present.  What version of Toad are you using?  Against what database/version? Maybe reword to make the question clearer? What errors did sqlplus throw? Ask in the comments what further info is needed to clarify.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you "execute as a script" by pressing F5. Make sure the editor window has this line before calling your procedure:

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited;
```

Here is an example calling a homegrown function that returns an element from a list (in this case the 6th element, "mirror") where the delimiter is a space.  Note you can view output on the "DBMS Output" tab too (click the "turn output on" button first).

[image: Click on the image to view full size]
Click on the image to view full size

Answer (score 0):

i found this little tricky button in jetBrains Datagrip, it turns on dbms_output without any dbms_output.enable or set serveron etc.

[image]